# Modal popup in mvc - icon link not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popupwindow

I am having problem with showing another view with a click of icon.

This is my markup:

```
 <h4 class="form-control-static ng-cloak">{{selectedFacility.Name}} <a href="@Url.Action("GetRrfForm","FacilityAdd")"><img src="/Content/PurchaseOrder.ico" style="width:30px;height:22px;margin-top:5px"> </a></h4>
```

The action method in my controller:

```
public class FacilityAddController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetRrfForm()
        {

            return View("ItemAddPopup");

        }
    }
```

I also tried to use `Url.RouteUrl()`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ItemEdit",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "FacilityAdd", action = "GetRrfForm"}
);

<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ItemEdit", new { controller = "FacilityAdd", action = "GetRrfForm"})"><img src="/Content/PurchaseOrder.ico" style="width:30px;height:40px;margin-top:5px"> </a>
```

Comment: Can you please describe your question with more information?

Comment: i cant seem to get the view i want when i click on the icon. Rather only the url is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
View("~/Views/Home/ItemAddPopup.cshtml")
```

should just be

```
View("ItemAddPopup")
```

You specify the **name** of the view, not the path, as noted here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: It doesnt still solve my problem. I did that, but the code doest even go to the controller when i debug :(

Comment: Okay, include an example of the generated HTML. Also update your question to include the name of the controller - the path you were originally using makes me suspect you're not using the framework correctly.

Comment: Some generated HTML helps narrow down the cause; we need to verify the URL that's generated by the helper. Also, did you recompile after updating the controller?

Comment: yes i recompiled everything. I dont seem to know how to view generated HTML 9am new at this). But the URL i get its http://localhost:7852/FacilityAdd/GetRrfForm

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio in Debug mode (and have an active debug session)? You can get the HTML that's rendered by right-clicking in your browser and selecting "View source", or by using the inspect tool in Firebug.

Comment: here is some of the viewsource coded <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var source1 =
                {
                    url: "../FacilityAdd/GetRRFGroup",
                    datatype: "json",
                    datafields: [{ name: "RRGroupID", type: "int" }, { name: "Name" }]
                };
                var dataAdapter1 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1);
                // Create a jqxDropDownList

Comment: You would want to edit that into the question, as comments are not meant for blocks of code. If you're trying to get the exact view your question shows so far, then the URL you're showing in that JavaScript is wrong ('GetRRFGroup' != 'GetRrfForm'). Beyond that, I don't know what library you're trying to use there.